# Inconsistent menu display among various devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am experiencing an issue where the top action bar icons are displayed well in certain device such as Galaxy s 5, and HTC X, but where the icons are poorly displayed in other device such as Motorola Droid, and others. I am not sure where the source of the problems comes from and have included pictures below to display my error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the xml file ? how are you using your layout files? hdpi, xhdpi layouts with respective drawables ? are the images you use have perfect sizes?

Comment: the icon size are small and remains the same across all the layout files

Comment: That may be the issue.. use the following layout files.
layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi,layout-xxhdpi,layout-sw600dp,layout-sw720dp

place images in the following respectivly.
drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-sw600dp,drawable-sw720dp

create actionbar.xml for all layouts with your requirements.
include this actionbar in other xml you need.. 

use this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in JAVA file it will hide the default action bar.

Comment: it indeed worked and this has resolved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following layout files. layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi,layout-xxhdpi,layout-sw600dp,layout-sw720dp place images in the following respectivly. drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-sw600dp,drawable-sw720dp create actionbar.xml for all layouts with your requirements. include this actionbar in other xml you need.. use this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in JAVA file it will hide the default action bar.